Show that there is a line between any pair of points on a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$
Show that there is a line through any pair of points in the plane.
Let the points be denoted by $v_1 =a_1 i +b_1 j + c_1 k; v_2= a_2 i+b_2 j + c_2 k$.
Then a line between them if it exists , would be of the form $(a_2-a_1)i+(b_2-b_1)j +(c_2-c_1)k$.
This however, doesn't prove that a line necessarily exists, it just gives its general form IF it exists.
Now my book has given a hint for this: Every line is of the form $ax+by+c=0$, however, I know that a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ isn't represented by such an equation.
Could I have a hint.

But this plane need NOT be the xy-plane , right?

A straight line in $\mathbb R^n$ interpolates lineraly between the points as vectors $(v_1,v_2).$
$$X(t) =  s \ v_1 + (1-s) \ v_2.$$ Its a curve passing both points with a constant direction (and velocity).
